# Adding padding to multiple divs inside a container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website with multiple sections and I'm encountering an issue in adding padding to the sections. I try to put the padding in the container, but it doesn't affect the individual divs. If I try to do it to the divs, it does it inside and the borders still touch. If I try and put the divs in more divs, it just doesn't go well. Whats going wrong? I'll show you my relative code:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.secbox {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  height: auto;
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are looking for margin not padding

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you, I cant believe I didn't realise

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="sec">
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
</div>
<div class="sec">
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
  <div class="secbox"> </div>
</div>
</div>




.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display:table
}
.sec{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.secbox {  
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 20px;
  margin:5px
}
```

Sample : [Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/hellosrini/y6sztxme/)